# Function Return List as Dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, return

My function below is taking a list of values and returning the counts of duplicates. I managed to make it count and print, but my task is to return it as a dictionary. I've been struggling to return in the correct format, any advice?

```
def counts(values):
    d = {}
    for val in values:
        d.setdefault(val,0)
        d[val] += 1
    for val, count in d.items():
        d = ("{} {}".format(val,count))
        return d
counts([1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,5]) # Should return →  {1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 4, 5: 1}
```

Comment: First advise, have a look at `collections.Counter`

Comment: You are reassigning `d` in your second for loop and immediately return it. Just `return d` after your first loop.

Comment: Ah, that's what I missed got it now.

Answer (score 1):

Just return the created dictionary:

```
def counts(values):
    d = {}
    for val in values:
        d.setdefault(val,0)
        d[val] += 1
    return d
```

Yields:

```
>>> counts([1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,5])
{1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 4, 5: 1}
```

Of course, as Moses points out, a `Counter` is built for this so just use that instead:

```
from collections import Counter

def counts(values):
    return dict(Counter(values))
```

Comment: I don't really enjoy earning reputation from answers like this, @MorganThrapp. I also want to preempt others from answering (and instead urge to edit this CW if they want to add anything)

Comment: If you don't think the question is deserving of an answer, why answer it?